# Banner Ads and Interstitial Ad Unit id Issue

Tags: android, admob

I am implementing  admob ads in android but Interstitial ads are not showing and only the banner shows.
is it required for the Banner Ads and the Interstitial Ads to have different Ad Unit ID in Admob Android?

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

```
     mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
     mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("myAdUnitId");

     // Create an ad request.
     AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();

     // Optionally populate the ad request builder.
     adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);

     // Set an AdListener.
     mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAdLoaded() {
             Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,
                     "The interstitial is loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onAdClosed() {
             // Proceed to the next level.
             goToNextLevel();
         }
     });

     // Start loading the ad now so that it is ready by the time the user is ready to go to
     // the next level.
     mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

     // Create the button to go to the next level.
     mNextLevelButton = new Button(this);
     mNextLevelButton.setText("Next Level");
     mNextLevelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             // Show the interstitial if it is ready. Otherwise, proceed to the next level
             // without ever showing it.
             if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                 mInterstitialAd.show();
             } else {
                 // Proceed to the next level.
                 goToNextLevel();
             }
         }
     });

     // Add the next level button to the layout.
     LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
     layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     layout.addView(mNextLevelButton);

     // Create a TextView to display the current level.
     mTextView = new TextView(this);
     mTextView.setText("Level 1");
     layout.addView(mTextView);

     setContentView(layout);
 }

 public void goToNextLevel() {
     // Show the next level (and disable the next level button since there are no more levels.
     mNextLevelButton.setEnabled(false);
     mTextView.setText("Level 2");
 }
}
```

[Here is a nice example on developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd#public-constructor-summary)

Answer (score 0):

Check your AD Type id.Very it both in your admob account and source code that the AD Unit Id belong to interstitial Ad.

If thats correct use this code

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
      // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();




        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("your id");
        AdRequest adReques = new AdRequest();

        interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(adReques);


    }
    private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");
        interstitialAd.ShowAd();
    }
```

Comment: hey friends give me any admob full demo? last time my account is terminate by admob